# Formula for exponential integral over a cone

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-polytopes, exponential-sums, cones

While reading 'Computing the Volume, Counting Integral points, and Exponential Sums' by A. Barvinok (1993), I came across the following:

"Moreover, let $K$ be the conic hull of linearly independent vectors $u_{1}, ..., u_{n}$ so $K = co(u_{1}, ..., u_{n})$. Denote by $K^{*} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: <x, y> \le 0  \text{ for all } y\in K\}$ the polar of K. Then for all $c \in \operatorname{Int} K^{*}$ we have

\begin{equation}
\int_{K}\exp(\langle c, x\rangle)dx = |u_{1} \land ... \land u_{n}|\prod_{i=1}^{n}\langle -c_{i}, u_{i}\rangle^{-1}
\end{equation}

To obtain the last formula we have to apply a suitable linear transformation to the previous integral. "

I have tried proving this but I can't find relevant links to help me. Also, I'm unsure what $|u_{1} \land ... \land u_{n}|$ is supposed to mean. Would greatly appreciate if someone could point me to a relevant resource or provide proof. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably more suitable for MathStackExchange. $u_1\wedge\ldots\wedge u_n$ is the determinant of the matrix with columns $u_j$. Why did you define the dual cone which does not appear in the formula? Is $c$ in the interior of that dual?

Comment: did some edits, made some mistakes. thanks for the feedback, managed to solve it now.